# Do not interfere of Bootstrap css in jQuery UI TimePicker

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, timepicker

I'm trying to use the [jQuery UI Timepicker](https://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/) but to enter with the bootstrap it this unconfiguring the css `jQuery UI TimePicker`.

Anyone know how to solve this problem because I need the bootstrap, but it can not interfere with css TimePicker.

Follows the code in [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rafaelcb21/ov80rcok/5/)

The bootstrap used:

`https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: Have you tried using a time picker that's explicitly compatible with Boostrap? That might be a little bit better than trying to get your choice of timepicker to work.

http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/

Comment: I searched for several, but none have the same layout than the `jQuery UI Timepicker`. You know some of the same layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just change the class name of the timepicker? Change the class timepicker in timepicker-test

```
.ui-widget { font-size: 12px; }

/*
 * Timepicker stylesheet
 * Highly inspired from datepicker
 * FG - Nov 2010 - Web3R 
 *
 * version 0.0.3 : Fixed some settings, more dynamic
 * version 0.0.4 : Removed width:100% on tables
 * version 0.1.1 : set width 0 on tables to fix an ie6 bug
 */

.ui-timepicker-test-inline { display: inline; }

#ui-timepicker-test-div { padding: 0.2em; background-color: #fff; }
.ui-timepicker-test-table { display: inline-table; width: 0; }
.ui-timepicker-test-table table { margin:0.15em 0 0 0; border-collapse: collapse; }

.ui-timepicker-test-hours, .ui-timepicker-test-minutes { padding: 0.2em;  }

.ui-timepicker-test-table .ui-timepicker-test-title { line-height: 1.8em; text-align: center; }
.ui-timepicker-test-table td { padding: 0.1em; width: 2.2em; }
.ui-timepicker-test-table th.periods { padding: 0.1em; width: 2.2em; }

/* span for disabled cells */
.ui-timepicker-test-table td span {
    display:block;
    padding:0.2em 0.3em 0.2em 0.5em;
    width: 1.2em;

    text-align:right;
    text-decoration:none;
}
/* anchors for clickable cells */
.ui-timepicker-test-table td a {
    display:block;
    padding:0.2em 0.3em 0.2em 0.5em;
    width: 1.2em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align:right;
    text-decoration:none;
}


/* buttons and button pane styling */
.ui-timepicker-test .ui-timepicker-test-buttonpane {
    background-image: none; margin: .7em 0 0 0; padding:0 .2em; border-left: 0; border-right: 0; border-bottom: 0;
}
.ui-timepicker-test .ui-timepicker-test-buttonpane button { margin: .5em .2em .4em; cursor: pointer; padding: .2em .6em .3em .6em; width:auto; overflow:visible; }
/* The close button */
.ui-timepicker-test .ui-timepicker-test-close { float: right }

/* the now button */
.ui-timepicker-test .ui-timepicker-test-now { float: left; }

/* the deselect button */
.ui-timepicker-test .ui-timepicker-test-deselect { float: left; }


/* IE6 IFRAME FIX (taken from datepicker 1.5.3 */
.ui-timepicker-test-cover {
    display: none; /*sorry for IE5*/
    display/**/: block; /*sorry for IE5*/
    position: absolute; /*must have*/
    z-index: -1; /*must have*/
    filter: mask(); /*must have*/
    top: -4px; /*must have*/
    left: -4px; /*must have*/
    width: 200px; /*must have*/
    height: 200px; /*must have*/
}
```